# How to copy multiple files from one folder to another with specific file names using php?

Tags: php, file, copy, directory

I have two folders which one of the folders is empty and the other one has 5 images files that named: image1, image2, image3, image4, and image5. I want to move or copy image2, image4, and image5 to another folder at the same time using php. How to copy multiple files from one folder to another with specific file names using php? Please help me with this, thank you in advanced.

Comment: sometimes calling the os's copy command is the best idea

Comment: can you show me how? with multiple files?

Comment: which os???????

Comment: already got the answers. thank you for help @nogad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rename function does this

Image rename

```
rename('image2.jpg', 'newfolder/image2.jpg');
rename('image4.jpg', 'newfolder/image4.jpg');
rename('image5.jpg', 'newfolder/image5.jpg');
```

If you want to keep the existing file on the same place you should use copy

Image copy

```
copy('image2.jpg', 'newfolder/image2.jpg');
copy('image4.jpg', 'newfolder/image4.jpg');
copy('image5.jpg', 'newfolder/image5.jpg');
```

Use Loop for multiple files as below:

```
//Create an array with image files which should be copy or move in new folder
$files = ['image2.jpg','image4.jpg','image5.jpg'];
foreach($files as $resFile){
    rename($resFile, 'newfolder/'.$resFile);
    copy($resFile, 'newfolder/'.$resFile);
}
```

Comment: Can we use loop instead?

Comment: Yes you can place the file names in array and use a loop for it. Please check the updated answer. You can use either rename or copy function as per your requirement.